# Object Class (polymorphism, casting)

Tags: java, class, object, casting, polymorphism

I'm a newbie learning Java and I just read about Object class as a superclass of all objects. I wonder now, if I want to create more classes (according to polymorphism rules) and the Object class is supposed to be "on top", can I create it or should I just treat it as "default"?

Comment: Welcome @Lucyna! What do you mean by "Polymorphism rules"? You can create a new class which extends another class you have created. So in theory if you have created two classes A and B. Your class B can extend class A. Even though you don't specify in the code, class A extends Object class. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Object` class in Java is the root of all classes.

Every class you create implicitly `extends Object`. Though those class definitions are equal:

```
class MyClass { }
class MyClass extends Object { }
```

The `extends Object` part is done for you automatically by the compiler.

If you have a class hierarchy, then the first class in this hierarchy is always (implicitly) `Object`:

```
class A { } // A will implicitly extend Object
class B extends A { } // though B is of type Object, too, because A is, too
```

That's the reason why you can cast everything (except for primitives) to `Object`:

```
A a = new A(); // works
B b = new B(); // works

Object a = new A(); // works, because A implicitly extends Object
Object b = new B(); // works, because B extends A, and A extends Object, and though B extends Object, too

A a = new B(); // works, because B extends A
B b = new A(); // fails, because A does not extend B
```

In general you **never** write `extends Object` yourself, because it is done for you automatically by Java.